# how to assign a value of xmlHttp.responseText to a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am new to ajax. I have a problem and cannot solve it. Please help me.. My Problem is, 
I send values to a servlet and get values. all other parts of codes work well. servlet returns a string: "val"(without quots) . Also when I print it in an alert, it shows "valid". it is ok. but in the if cluase, it returns false. that means; "valid"==xmlHttp.responseText  returns false. ( but xmlHttp.responseText shows valid in alert. ) how can get executed alert("move to next page")?

```
          function parseResults() {
            alert("parseresult");
            invalid="invalid" ;
            valid="valid";
            var res =xmlHttp.responseText;

        alert("responseTExt is : "+xmlHttp.responseText); // shows in alert: valid
        alert("result is: "+res);// shows: valid

        if(valid=res){
            alert("move to next Page");
        }            
        if(invalid==res){
                alert("invalid username or password");
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check exactly your `if` statement and all values. 
In question example is `if(valid=res)` which is wrong:

- `=` assign, not compare values (maybe is just typo in example above).
- You said that `res` value is *val*, but you compare it with *valid*, which gives `false`.

I assume it doesn't work because of some typos (wrong values, missing `==` operator, blank characters in compared values).

Answer (score 0):

missing a "="?

```
    if(valid==res){
        alert("move to next Page");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

valid==res instead of valid=res in the if condition